# Integração Contínua - Teste e PRD no mesmo servidor com docker-compose e Travis-CI

Tags: docker, travis-ci

Tenho um sistema em Java com Spring rodando num container Docker com docker-compose.
A Integração funciona com GitHub >> Travis-CI >> Docker (no servidor).

Estou tentando montar duas aplicações do mesmo repositório (uma de teste e outra de produção) no mesmo servidor (cada uma respondendo em sua porta).
Mas toda vez que faço um `docker-compose pull` no container de teste ele atualiza a imagem, e consequentemente a atualiza os dois containers (teste e produção).

Não tenho tanta experiência com docker, mas acredito que isso deve estar ocorrendo por conta da imagem que é única.

Qual seria o melhor formato pra conseguir individualizar o `pull` de cada container?
Talvez montar duas imagens? Se for este o caminho, alguém saberia me dizer como consigo configurar o docker-compose.yml para montar duas imagens a partir do mesmo repositório?

Meu docker-compose.yml está assim

```css
version: '3.4'
services:
  db-easy:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      TZ: America/Sao_Paulo
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *************
      MYSQL_USER: easy
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: *********
      MYSQL_DATABASE: easy
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    networks:
      - easy-network
  easy-call:
    image: agcaldeira/easy-call
    restart: always
    working_dir: /EasyCall
    environment:
      TZ: America/Sao_Paulo
    ports:
      - "80:8080" 
    command: mvn spring-boot:run
    depends_on:
      - db-easy
    networks:
      - easy-network
networks:
    easy-network:
        driver: bridge
```

No servidor tenho dois docker-compose.yml bem semelhante. As únicas diferenças são as portas externas.
Se alguém souber como resolvo isso me dá um help por favor.

Obrigado.

Comment: use nomes de serviços diferentes, por exemplo `easy-call` e `easy-call-tests`

Comment: Oi @Ricardo, obrigado por responder.

Fiz esta alteração mas ele continua com uma única imagem, realizei o `pull`, ele atualizou a imagem (única) e marcou ela como latest.

Ao reiniciar os container os dois foram atualizados (mesmo fazendo o pull somente em teste).
Segue abaixo um trecho do docker-compose.yml de teste:

  easy-call-test:
    image: agcaldeira/easy-call
    restart: always
    working_dir: /EasyCall
    environment:
      TZ: America/Sao_Paulo
 
Teria alguma sugestão?

Obrigado.